# Problems with Jquery Script not hitting a WebMethod

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, webmethod

I have the following JQuery script :-

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#languageMenu").change(function () {
                var value = $("#languageMenu option:selected").val();
                setSession(value);
            });

            function setSession(val) {
                alert(val);

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Dashboard.aspx/SetUserCulture",
                    data: JSON.stringify(val),
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8;",
                    success: function () {
                        __doPostBack('UPMainMenu', '');
                        __doPostBack('UPContent', '');
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Fail");
                    }
                });
            };

        });

    </script>
```

However its always throwing a fail and never hitting my WebMethod.  My WebMethod in C# is :-

```
        [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public static void SetUserCulture(string lang)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentUI"] = lang;
        String selectedLanguage = lang;

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
            CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(selectedLanguage);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new
            CultureInfo(selectedLanguage);

    }
```

I cannot seem to figure out why its not hitting my WebMethod.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Thanks for your help and time

*********** UPDATE ******************************************************

```
            $(document).ready(function () {


            $("#languageMenu").change(function () {
                var value = $("#languageMenu option:selected").val();
                setSession(value);
            });

            function setSession(lang) {
                alert(lang);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Dashboard.aspx/SetUserCulture",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: "{'lang':'" + lang + "'}",
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8;",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                        __doPostBack('UPMainMenu', '');
                        __doPostBack('UPContent', '');
                    },
                    error: function (e) {
                        console.log(e);
                    }
                });
            };

        });
```

******** *SECOND UPDATE* **********************************

```
            $(document).ready(function () {


            $("#languageMenu").change(function () {
                var value = $("#languageMenu option:selected").val();
                setSession(value);
            });

            function setSession(lang) {
                alert(lang);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Dashboard.aspx/SetUserCulture",
                    data: "{'lang':'" + JSON.stringify(lang) + "'}",
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8;",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function() {
                        __doPostBack('UPMainMenu', '');
                        __doPostBack('UPContent', '');
                    },
                    error: function() {
                         alert("Fail");
                    }
                });

            };

        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ResolveUrl will give you url understood by request

```
var pageUrl = '<%= ResolveUrl("~/Default.aspx")%>';
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#languageMenu").change(function () {
        var value = $("#languageMenu option:selected").val();
        setSession(value);
    });

    setSession('testing');

    function setSession(lang) {
        alert(lang);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: pageUrl + "/SetUserCulture",
            data: "{'lang':'" + JSON.stringify(lang) + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8;",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function () {
                alert('success');
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Fail");
            }
        });

    };

});
```

Comment: is 'Default.aspx' in you root folder?

Comment: actually its Dashboard.aspx and yes it is in my root

Comment: Cinek I am going to mark your answer as the answer.  What I did was try this code in the page I had and in another test page.  In the test page it worked, so its nothing to do with this code, but some other thing on the hosting page.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try to write your `$.ajax` method call like this:

```
function setSession(val) {
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/SetUserCulture",
        data: "{'lang':'"+ val + "'}", // Note this portion
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8;",
        success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
        __doPostBack('UPMainMenu', '');
        __doPostBack('UPContent', '');
       },
      error: function (e) {
         console.log(e);
      }
  });
}
```

Because your `web method` has `lang` parameter passed, so in the ajax call you might have to specify that. though there are many different ways to do that but i have comeup with this solution. *I tried to call my web method and it worked*.

**Note:**

If it is a valid json object like `{'lang':'hi'}` then jQuery might not send it as json data but instead serialize it to `lang=hi` thus you get the error. _Previously it was not passed at all.

Thanks

Comment: Hey Dado I am still getting a Fail like this, and the breakpoint is never hit

Comment: try `error: function (e) {console.log(e);}` as i have successfully achieved this thing. just few mins ago. :)

Comment: Then check for the errors in console it might be very useful.

Comment: tried it with error: function (e) {console.log(e);} but nothing happened, no breakpoint hit

Comment: @cinek it will not work, will give `Cannot convert object of type \u0027System.String\u0027 to type \u0027System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary... bla bla bla`

Comment: @Johann i am suggesting you to check browser console apart from the `alert('fail')`

Comment: $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Dashboard.aspx/SetUserCulture",
            data: "{'lang':'"+ JSON.stringify(val)+"'}",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8;",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function () {
                __doPostBack('UPMainMenu', '');
                __doPostBack('UPContent', '');
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Fail");
            }
        });
this worked for me

Comment: removed dataType: "json" and put contentType: "text/html", still not working though

Comment: @Johann `{'lang':'"+ JSON.stringify(val)+"'}` try with this as cinek sugessted with `dataType:json`

Comment: @Cinek Tried your code still not working, though alert ("Fail ") is not displaying now

Comment: "Dashboard.aspx/SetUserCulture" - make sure it's an absolute path, use '<%= ResolveUrl("~/Dashboard.aspx")%>'

Comment: @Cinek Updated my question with your answer

Comment: @Cinek tried                         url: "<%= ResolveUrl("~/Dashboard.aspx/SetUserCulture")%>",
no luck though

Answer (score 0):

What Dado said - in the ajax call you must specify parameter name.

But you are passing a simple string, don't need JSON for that - just skip

```
contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8;",
```

and use

```
contentType: "text/html",
```